# Bootstrap : order elements with the 'navbar-right' class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When using the `navbar-right` class on several elements, it seems I have to order the latters in the opposite way I want them to be displayed.

For instance, on the right of my navbar, I want a search form, and the the user icon. So, I did that :

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

However, if I do that, the user icon is on the right of the search bar...

The only work around I found is to write that :

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
</ul>
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Which does exactly what I want, but I don't think it's the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap advise on their website there is issues with applying `.navbar-right` to multiple elements

> Right aligning multiple components Navbars currently have a limitation
>   with multiple .navbar-right classes. To properly space content, we use
>   negative margin on the last .navbar-right element. When there are
>   multiple elements using that class, these margins don't work as
>   intended. We'll revisit this when we can rewrite that component in v4.

I suggest putting the form inside the `<ul></ul>` tags.

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, applying your solution makes my right elements "stack" on top of eachothers, rather than being on the same line

Comment: You may need to put the form after the opening <ul> tag, here is an example of mine, https://github.com/Maximumz/maximumz.github.io/blob/master/online-image-store/conf/header.php although it's form last in my case.